# Hosting Server in Local Machine

Tags: windows, server, hosting

I'm trying to host my website (http://www.example.com/) on Local Machine having Window 10 except hosting it on Godaddy Server OR any other like this hosting server provider, can you please guide me how can I do that?, is it possible? what security check should be checked?

I came across some article but did not found them useful such as
[this article](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-ftp-server-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

it's generally more convenient to start with more server-oriented OS such as windows server or some distributions of Linux.

you will need to request static IP from your ISP, purchase a domain or try out a DDNS service such as NO-IP.

in windows 10 you can use several hosting software such as Apache's webserver

you will need to open to relevant ports in your router and forword them to your server. pay close attestation to the ports you open as they can be a huge venerability. keep in mind that your IP address will be exposed.

Comment: thanks for sharing knowledge, can I get a step by step guide for it? because I'm new to it

Comment: if you decide to use appache webserver (most common) then the appache documetaion contains all the info you need.